# Not able to use methods generated by groovy @Delegate from java classes

Tags: java, groovy, delegates, compiler-errors, intellij-idea

when running the code below
i'm getting compilation error:
java: ..\JavaClass.java:8: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method add(java.math.BigDecimal)
location: class BigDecimalDelegated

it seems like the stub of the groovy class created for the java compiler does not contain the delegated methods.

any idea?

consider this classes:

```
class BigDecimalDelegated  //groovy class
{
    @Delegate BigDecimal delegated;
    String data;
}

import org.junit.Test;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
public class JavaClass  //java class
{
    @Test
    public void temp()throws Exception
    {
        new BigDecimalDelegated().add(BigDecimal.TEN);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy compiler used in IDEA's external build doesn't support this, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-4647

You can either use @Delegate classes from Groovy code only, or switch off external build in Settings | Compiler to use the old build mechanism.

Comment: The link provided describes another scenario... in my case i don't expect the Class to Implement interface containing the 'add()' method.i expect it to have such a method. Oh and thank you :)

Comment: It's the same problem: Groovy's own stub generator doesn't take @Delegate into account

Answer (score 0):

How are you running/compiling the code?

Also, I believe you'll need to set delegated in the constructor for BigDecimalDelegated

```
class BigDecimalDelegated  //groovy class
{
    @Delegate BigDecimal delegated
    String data

    BigDecimalDelegated() {
      delegated = 0.0G
    }
}
```

Comment: i compile and running the code using IntelliJ 12. i constructor isn't important because i cant compile the code. i will be happy for a NullPointerException

Comment: Just downloaded IntelliJ 12, and see what you mean.  Found a bug here http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78555 but it says that it's fixed...  Odd... I'm stumped :-(

Comment: I saw that bug while searching for answer. i wasn't sure it was the same and as you said it supposed to be fixed.

Comment: If I change the test to be a `.groovy` file instead of a `.java` one, it works :-/